# API to fetch the contacts from domain email address

Tags: email

I have get the contacts from gmail,hotmail and yahoo email providers.
And i want to get  contacts from any domain email addresss which users enter in a textbox. Is it feasible?

For example,
Here we can see the hotmail contact import: https://techjoomla.com/invitex/how-to-use-hotmailrest-api-to-import-contacts.html

Same way i want to import contacts from a domain email. i.e say if i have this email address test@stackoverflow.com and having few contacts.

Using PHP, i want to fetch the contacts from test@stackoverflow.com

Hope the above provided detailed explaination.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please, explain more.

Comment: i have updated my question please review it

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want is possible if that mail server allows you to access the contacts you have there. But, I am pretty sure that you will definitely not be allowed to fetch contacts from every single mail server you want. But, I would suggest you to give that try before losing hope.

Comment: Thanks Aniruddh. I have tried searching over hours and hours. But not able to find a solution. Do you know api for this call?

Comment: You don't have to search for this everywhere just go to that website from which you want to fetch the contact list and check the developer options on that website. If there is any place where you can find the solution then that is the only place.